# Shiny: updateSelectInput() selected argument issue with observe()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using `observe()` to change a value of a `selectInput` after a user selects `TRUE/FALSE` in the *Categorical* drop down list. In the first tab of my program if you set *Categorical* to `TRUE` then *Impute* gets updated to `mode` and `mean` otherwise. I'm then able to change the *Impute* value as desired without it reverting to the value that appears when `TRUE/FALSE` is selected.

In the second tab I have a multiple `selectInput` list with a similar interface as the first tab; the interface is created for every value selected in *Select covariates*. In this section I also used `observe()` to update each selected covariates' *Impute* drop down list accordingly to the logic of the first tab (i.e. if `TRUE` is selected then *Impute* gets updated to `mode` and `mean` otherwise). However, the value in *Impute* appers to be locked in the sense that I'm not able to switch between values as I did in the first tab.

I don't know how to correct this issue and I was wondering if anyone out there has encountered this similar problem and has been able to fix it. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

The code to my app can be seen below and can be ran in a single file.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("Test",id="navbarPage",
             tabPanel("First tab", id = "first_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput('covariate.L.categorical', 'Categorical', c("",TRUE,FALSE)),
                          selectInput('covariate.L.impute', "Impute", c("","default","mean","mode","median"))
                        ),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Second tab", id = "second_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput('covariates', 'Select covariates', choices = c("age","sex","race","bmi"), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE), 
                          tags$hr(),
                          uiOutput("covariateop")
                        ),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             ))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(cov.selected = NULL)
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "covariate.L.impute", selected = ifelse(input$covariate.L.categorical,"mode","mean"))
  })
  
  output$covariateop <- renderUI({  
    lapply(input$covariates, function(x){
      
      tags$div(id = paste0("extra_criteria_for_", x),
               h4(x),
               selectInput(paste0(x,"_categorical"), "Categorical",
                           choices = c("",TRUE,FALSE)),
               selectInput(paste0(x,"_impute"), "Impute",
                           choices = c("","default","mean","mode","median")),
               textInput(paste0(x,"_impute_default_level"), "Impute default level"),
               tags$hr()
      )
    })
  })
  observe({
    lapply(input$covariates, function(x){
      updateSelectInput(session, paste0(x,"_impute"), selected = ifelse(as.logical(reactiveValuesToList(input)[[paste0(x,"_categorical")]])==TRUE,"mode","mean"))
    })
  })
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `observe` in the second tab, you use `reactiveValuesToList(input)[[paste0(x,"_categorical")]]`. This means that this observe is reactive to any changes in any `input` element, so also if you change the "Imputation" input. You can just use `input[[paste0(x,"_categorical")]]` instead to get rid of this behaviour.

Note that the implementation of dynamic UI with `lapply` leads to the deletion and anew rendering of already existing input selections when an additional variable is selected. Maybe you can have a look at `insertUI`/`removeUI` to get a bit nicer UI.